# Getting deprecation errors after installing angularx-social-login

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-core, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to implement login with google in asp.net core 5 and AngularJs. After reading some tutorials on this, I have found this package. So I have installed it via npm:

```
npm i angularx-social-login
```

Then did nessesary imports:

```
import { SocialLoginModule, SocialAuthServiceConfig } from 'angularx-social-login';
import { GoogleLoginProvider } from 'angularx-social-login';
```

And then configured the providers:

```
providers: [
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: AuthorizeInterceptor, multi: true },

     {
      provide: 'SocialAuthServiceConfig',
      useValue: {
        autoLogin: false,
        providers: [
          {
            id: GoogleLoginProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
            provider: new GoogleLoginProvider(
              '883654869277-m2mlgsroh8vsmt0tg82lmo4cnt0cuqs3.apps.googleusercontent.com'
            )
          },
        ],
      } as SocialAuthServiceConfig
    },

  ],
```

But then I run the application, I am getting this error:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices: Error: (node:13652) [DEP0111] DeprecationWarning: Access to process.binding('http_parser') is deprecated.

Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices: Error: (Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
```

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NavMenuComponent } from './nav-menu/nav-menu.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { CounterComponent } from './counter/counter.component';
import { FetchDataComponent } from './fetch-data/fetch-data.component';
import { ApiAuthorizationModule } from 'src/api-authorization/api-authorization.module';
import { AuthorizeGuard } from 'src/api-authorization/authorize.guard';
import { AuthorizeInterceptor } from 'src/api-authorization/authorize.interceptor';

import { SocialLoginModule, SocialAuthServiceConfig } from 'angularx-social-login'; import { GoogleLoginProvider } from 'angularx-social-login';

//config gauth

//end gauth

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavMenuComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    CounterComponent,
    FetchDataComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule.withServerTransition({ appId: 'ng-cli-universal' }),
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    SocialLoginModule,
    ApiAuthorizationModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: '', component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: 'counter', component: CounterComponent },
      { path: 'fetch-data', component: FetchDataComponent, canActivate: [AuthorizeGuard] },
    ])
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: AuthorizeInterceptor,

      multi: true
    },
    {
      provide: 'SocialAuthServiceConfig',
      useValue: {
        autoLogin: false,
        providers: [
          {
            id: GoogleLoginProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
            provider: new GoogleLoginProvider(
              '883654869277-m2mlgsroh8vsmt0tg82lmo4cnt0cuqs3.apps.googleusercontent.com'
            )
          },
        ],
      } as SocialAuthServiceConfig
    }
  ],

  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

What can I do to make it work?

Comment: @Bodan please post your all ```app.module.ts```  file.

Comment: Got it... Please check it out.

Comment: looking like everything is ok. i will suggest you read this article https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-to-sign-in-with-google-in-angular-and-use-jwt-based-net-core-api-authentication-rsa-6635719fb86c

Answer (score 1):

angularx-social-login is no longer being maintained and deprecated.

If you check out their npm documentation they recommend moving to `@abacritt/angularx-social-login`.

ref: https://www.npmjs.com/package/angularx-social-login

Might help you out to git rid of depreciation warnings/errors.